# Lot size for NASDAQ Equity options

Tags: stock-markets, stock-exchanges, call-options, put-options, nasdaq

I'm going to trade in NASDAQ equity options, please share link where I can find lot size of each equity option contract?

Answer (score 2):

Exchange traded equity options are for 100 shares per contract unless they have been adjusted due to a corporate action such as a fractional or reverse stock split, a special dividend, merger, etc.

Comment: for AAPL I heard it is only 10 before split, is it correct?

Comment: When there's a whole stock split (there's a "1" in the second part of the ratio), there will be a proportional increase in the number of contracts and a proportional decrease in the option strike price. So if you own one $500  call and there's a 5 for 1 split then after the split you would own 5 calls with a $100 strike price.  Pre and post split, the contract is for 100 shares. Fractional splits (like 3 for 2) cause the number of shares per contract to change.

Comment: other than this I heard for big shares lot size will be less than 100? is this correct?